# ListView widget is not scrolling

Tags: flutter

I am making a simple app.The post widget is not scrolling.I have used **ListView** widget and also given **shrinkWrap** property to true. Only the widget above the post is scroll but the post widget is not scrolling.

postbar.dart

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

home.dart

```
class _homeState extends State<home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      child: ListView(
        
        children: [
          postbar(),
          Divider(thickness: 2,),
         storybar(),
         Divider(thickness: 2,),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
           child: post()
      ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

post.dart

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<Posts>>(
            future: fetchPost(),
            builder: ((context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data!.length, shrinkWrap: true, itemBuilder: (context,i){
                // for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i++) {
                  bool a=false;
                  return Container(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [ childrens]
                       )
                      )
                   })
                }
             })
            }
       


     The only postbar and storybar is scrolling but not post.
```

Comment: can you try removing singlechildscroll view and keep post inside listview?

Comment: I have tried,but not working...

Comment: could you include postbar() too?

Comment: ok , I will include

Comment: do you want List view scroll or just SingleChildScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the main listView just scroll you can set post's listview physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics, like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Posts>>(
        future: fetchPost(),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //<----- add this
                itemCount: 10,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  // for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i++) {
                  bool a = false;
                  return Container(
                    child: Column(children: [childrens]),
                  );
                });
          }
        }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be causing this:

1. Make sure that your ListView is inside of a SingleChildScrollView. This will allow the ListView to scroll.
2. Make sure that you are using a ListView.builder() rather than a ListView() widget. This will allow the ListView to scroll.
3. Make sure that you have set the shrinkWrap property to true. This will allow the ListView to scroll.
4. Make sure that you are using a ListView.separated() widget rather than a ListView() widget. This will allow the ListView to scroll.
5. Finally, make sure that you are using the proper constraints. If you are using a Column widget, make sure that the main axis is set to vertical. If you are using a Row widget, make sure that the main axis is set to horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

While the parent widget handling scroll event, you can use `Column` widget to return children instead of using ListView,

```dart
builder: ((context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Column(children: [
      for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i++)
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [],
          ),
        )
    ]);
  }
```

It seems like you were trying to using looping with extra variable, you can create inline function like

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      ...() {
        List<Widget> items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i++) {
          items.add(Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [],
            ),
          ));
        }
        return items;
      }()
    ],
  );
}
```

Also mapping the list

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return Column(
    children: snapshot.data!.map(
      (e) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [],
          ),
        );
      },
    ).toList(),
  );
}
```